# Basis of a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis for the Pol$_3(\mathbb{R})$ vector space (polynomials of degree 3 or less), we've got a basis of the following form; $$\{1,p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x)\}$$
Now, I'd like to show that this is a basis. Since every polynomial in the vector space is of form \begin{align}a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3\end{align}
I first write $$e1 + fp_1(x) + gp_2(x) + hp_3(x)$$ where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h are constants. I then manipulate above so that it becomes of the same form as the polynomials from the vector space, and then equate the constant $a$ with some combination of $e,f,g,h$ and likewise for $b,c$ and $d$.

That gives a linear system of equations. If the corresponding matrix has a non-zero determinant.... is this not enough to prove that our set is a basis? Because I've shown that it spans the set, as I can choose constants $e,f,g,h$ in such that I can express any polynomial in the vector space with my basis.... and since the determinant of the matrix is non-zero, I can do this in only one way?

Comment: Yes that is enough. If the determinant $\det A \not = 0$ then the matrix $A$ is invertible and we have a unique solution to $Ax=b$ given by $x = A^{-1}b$

Comment: If you want a theorem to refer to we have the [Invertible matrix theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) (if one point on the list holds then so does all the others). For this case see Point 18 ($\det A \not =0$) and Point 6 (we have a unique solution).

Comment: If you've already shown that $\{1,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ span Pol${}_3(\Bbb R)$, and you know that Pol${}_3(\Bbb R)$ has dimension $4$ (for example, by already knowing that $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ is a basis), then you can immediately deduce that $\{1,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is a basis. In a finite-dimension vector space, every spanning set of the right size is a basis (as is every linearly independent set of the right size). - Side note: I assume you know some information about $p_1,p_2,p_3$, because not every set of the form $\{1,p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is a spanning set or basis.